# How to run full-icu with nodemon?

Tags: node.js, gulp, nodemon

When I try to run `full-icu` with `nodemon`, it doesn't add the localization support as expected.

I've tried to include `full-icu` via an environment variable, which I load with `dotenv`, then via CLI, none had worked yet. I'm running Node.js 12.3.1, nodemon 1.19.1, full-icu 1.3.0.

CLI:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const {spawn} = require('child_process');

gulp.task('nodemon', () =>
{
    const {stdout, stderr} = spawn('nodemon.cmd', ['--icu-data-dir=/node_modules/full-icu']);
    //...
});
```

.env:

```
NODE_ICU_DATA=/node_modules/full-icu
```

Also, I've tried to remove the first slash or include the absolute path without any success.

When I run:

`console.log(Intl.NumberFormat.supportedLocalesOf('sk');`

The output should be `['sk']`, but is actually `[]` for any language other than English.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it by changing `"start"` in `"scripts"` in `package.json` from:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./app"
}
```

to:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node --icu-data-dir=node_modules/full-icu ./app"
}
```

The problem with the CLI was probably a wrong order of the variables because `--icu-data-dir` was preceded by `./app`. And I guess the problem with the environment variable was that I'd added it after the initialization of the process and Node didn't check it afterwards. If that's not the case, I'd like to be corrected.